# How do I add a HTML Table to my data and retain Google Sheets formatting

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

My email script works and sends the Google Sheet range. The problem is the columns vary in width depending on the data in the cells. So I need the code to format the data to a table and keep the formatting for the phone number.

I do not know how to fix

```js
function SendEmail() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('LOOKUP');
  var to = s.getRange('G4').getValue();
  var data = s.getRange('A36:E91').getValues();
  var body = '';
  for (var row in data) {
    for (var col in data[row]) {
      body += data[row][col] + '\t';
    }
    body += '\n';
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(to, 'This Is Your Current Bus Roster', body);
}
```

The email body data columns need to be a fixed width so they all line up from top to bottom.

Comment: In addition to the answer below, use `getDisplayValues()` instead of `getValues()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send an email with a HTML body by adding a fourth parameter to your `MailApp.sendMail`.  Adding `<head>` and `<style>` tags will let you format the table. ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)))

```js
function SendEmail() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('LOOKUP');
  var to = s.getRange('G4').getValue();
  var data = s.getRange('A36:E91').getValues();
  var body = '<head><style>' /* + your css here */ + '</style></head><table>';
  for (var row in data) {
    body += '<tr>';
    for (var col in data[row]) {
      body += '<td>' + data[row][col] + '</td>';
    }
    body += '</tr>';
  }
  body += '</table>';
  MailApp.sendEmail(to, 'This Is Your Current Bus Roster', '', {htmlBody: body});
}
```

However, I would recommend going one step further and taking advantage of the [HTMLService class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service) and a template.  In the template you can add `<head>` and `<style>` tags so you can format your table exactly how you want.

```js
function SendEmail() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('LOOKUP');
  var to = s.getRange('G4').getValue();
  var data = s.getRange('A36:E91').getValues();
  var body = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('email');
  body.data = data;
  body = body.evaluate().getContent();
  MailApp.sendEmail(to, 'This Is Your Current Bus Roster', '', {htmlBody: body});
}
```

file "email.html": ([Templated HTML documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates))

```html
<head>
  <style>
    /* style your table here */
  </style>
</head>
<table>
<? for (var row in data) { ?>
  <tr>
<?   for (var col in data[row]) { ?>
  <td> <?= data[row][col] ?> </td>
<?   } ?>
  </tr>
<? } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: The htmlBody script at the top and the HtmlService script produce identical emails.

Comment: So i need to add the template to set the column widths. I do know how.
Where does the <head> and <style> code in the script? (Complete script) Also can you provide some of the information for the question marks?

Comment: @bciepiela10gmailcom the `<? ?>` tags are explained in the link I placed above that section: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates .  I would suggest writing out your CSS in the template directly, rather than putting it in the JavaScript, unless you have a really good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: @bciepiela10gmailcom I added where you can add the <head> and <style> tags in the pure javascript version, if that was what you were asking.  If I am misunderstanding your comment, my apologies and feel free to try and clarify again.

Comment: Thank you, works great!
Do I open a new question or can you tell me?
I want to get two email addresses one in G4 and also G23.
How do I correct this to do that, var to = s.getRange('G4').getValue();

Comment: And send the email to two people

Comment: @bciepiela10gmailcom the `to` parameter of `sendEmail` takes as many emails as you want in a single comma separated string, e.g. `var to = "me@ex.com,you@ex.com"`.  There are many ways to achieve that final result.  You could keep the declaration (`var to = s.getRange('G4').getValue();`) and then add `to += "," + s.getRange('G23').getValue();` to append a comma and the 2nd address into string `to`.  Extra advice: in a single function, it is usually better to grab all sheet data with `sheet.getDataRange().getValues();` and work with that array rather than multiple `.getValue()` calls.